# How do you delimit Beamer frames and blocks in LyX?

Tags: beamer, lyx, block

I’m a new LyX user, and I would like to make a Beamer presentation.  But I don’t understand how to perform some absolutely basic functions:

- inserting a block in a frame that does not have one yet
- defining the end of a frame so you can type content within the frame
- defining the end of a block so that you can both type content within the block and type content outside the block but within the frame

So can someone walk me through how to do these things in LyX?  I’m an absolute beginner.  Does it involve somehow inserting vertical and/or horizontal markup or separator lines?

Comment: * `\begin{block}{...} ... \end{block}` * `\begin{frame}\frametitle{...} ... \end{frame}`

Comment: @marmot That’s how to do it in LaTeX, but how do I do it in LyX?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan have you read Help > Specific Manuals > Beamer Presentations?

Comment: @scottkosty Yes, I have.  I couldn’t find the information I was looking for in it.  It talked about frames and blocks but it didn’t talk about these three things as far as I could tell.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Ah I see. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

As @Marmot pointed out the TeX code frames need to be declared to beamer so you could simply add it as Evil Red Text (ctrl L)

[image]

Comment: There’s no way to do it in the GUI without writing LaTeX code?  In the rightclick menus I’m getting lots of options like insert block above and insert separated frame and the like.

Comment: The example above is to show how to "keep it stupidly simple" for a absolutely basic functions block in frame approach, which @marmot answered what you asked for. My answer is the visualisation of that in LyX  If you want to see complex there are as many ways as users but go to **File New from template** and say select beamer conference that is more the time consuming all sing all dancing way.

Comment: I don’t need to start from scratch, I already have a Beamer presentation TeX file which I have imported into LyX.  But what I’m trying to figure out is do things like adding blocks to existing frames and the like.  And if possible I would like to avoid doing any LaTeX code.

Comment: @marmot If there was a LyX stackexchange I would ask there.  Anyway LyX is on-topic here, so hopefully someone will know the answer to my question.

Comment: Of, course, without using any LaTeX code you can insert frames and block with the left  dropdown menu (Frame,PlainFrame,FragileFrame) and start new frames with the menu Insert  > Separate Frame Above/Bellow. Said that, it is worth to mention that  I make Beamer documents in Rmarkdown, Rmarkdown+LaTeX or pure LaTeX, but never in LyX, because I found the  LyX GUI not  very handy for Beamer presentations.

Comment: @Fran Can you post an answer?  How do I access the left dropdown menu?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan in a ***new*** document, you should have a white box with say "Standard" , on the left upper corner, (under File and Edit menu).  If you click on it you will see many other options ( "LyX-code", "Quotation", Etc.) ***If*** you have configure that new document to be a Beamer presentation, you will see that some of the options are "Frame","plainFrame", etc. Make the first frame is just click on "Frame".

Comment: @Fran Thank you so much!  That solved my problem.  If you post that as an answer I’d be happy to accept it.